# Service Broker error when ending a conversation. Second attempt

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Let me rephrase my [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/284938/service-broker-error-when-ending-a-conversation) because issue reproduction is much simpler than I thought.

When I close Service Broker dialogs sometimes I get a message *The remote conversation endpoint is either in a state where no more messages can be exchanged, or it has been dropped.*

Repro. There are two mssql instances ( hosted on different Azure VMs ) with aliases *servicebrokersender* and *servicebrokertarget*.

```
-- on both sides
create master key
create certificate
create service broker endpoint
create certificate from the peer
grant connect to endpoint
```

```
-- servicebrokersender
use master
go
-- create sender DBs
declare @i int = 1
      , @cmd varchar(max);

while ( @i <= 10 )
begin

    set @cmd = '
    create database serviceBrokertest_' + cast( @i as varchar ) + '
    alter database serviceBrokertest_' + cast( @i as varchar ) + ' set enable_broker
    '
    exec ( @cmd );

    set @i += 1;
end
go
-- create service broker objects in sender DBs
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)
      , @name sysname
declare cur cursor  local fast_forward for
select name from sys.databases
  where name like 'serviceBrokertest_%' 
open cur
fetch next from cur into @name
while ( @@fetch_status = 0 )
begin
   select @cmd = '  use [' + @name + ']
                    create message type [test_message] validation = none;
                    create contract [test_contract] ( [test_message] sent by any );
                    create queue dbo.sender_queue_outbound with status = on, retention = off, poison_message_handling ( status = off ) on [default];
                    create service [servicebrokersender_' + @name + '_outbound] on queue sender_queue_outbound( test_contract );
                 '
  exec ( @cmd )
  fetch next from cur into @name
end
close cur
deallocate cur
go
```

```
-- servicebrokertarget
-- create target DB and Service Broker objects
create database serviceBrokertestTargetDb
alter database serviceBrokertestTargetDb set enable_broker

use serviceBrokertestTargetDb
go
create message type [test_message] validation = none;
create contract [test_contract] ( [test_message] sent by any );
create queue dbo.target_queue_inbound with status = on, retention = off, poison_message_handling ( status = off ) on [default];
create service serviceBrokertestTargetDb_inbound on queue target_queue_inbound( test_contract );
go
select service_broker_guid from sys.databases where name = db_name() -- 5405D327-1DD9-4E22-BFE3-23008129E971
go
```

Сreating routes

```
-- servicebrokersender
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)
      , @name sysname
declare cur cursor  local fast_forward for
select name from sys.databases
  where name like 'serviceBrokertest_%' 
open cur
fetch next from cur into @name
while ( @@fetch_status = 0 )
begin
   select @cmd = '  use [' + @name + ']
                    create route [route_to_serviceBrokertestTargetDb_inbound] with service_name = ''serviceBrokertestTargetDb_inbound'', address = ''TCP://servicebrokertarget:4022'', broker_instance = ''5405D327-1DD9-4E22-BFE3-23008129E971'';
                 '
  exec ( @cmd )
  fetch next from cur into @name
end
close cur
deallocate cur
go
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)
      , @name sysname
drop table if exists #t;
create table #t( s sysname, d uniqueidentifier )
declare cur cursor  local fast_forward for
select name from sys.databases
  where name like 'serviceBrokertest_%' 
open cur
fetch next from cur into @name
while ( @@fetch_status = 0 )
begin
   select @cmd = '  use [' + @name + ']
                    select ( select name from sys.services where service_id > 65535 ) as s, ( select service_broker_guid from sys.databases where name = db_name() ) as d 
                 '
  insert into #t
    exec ( @cmd )
  fetch next from cur into @name
end
close cur
deallocate cur
go
select 'route_to' + s, * from #t
go
```

```
-- servicebrokertarget
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_1_outbound]    with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_1_outbound'   , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = '8D9F2117-76D6-4000-9902-C5E509AFC15B';
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_10_outbound]   with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_10_outbound'  , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = 'D1C6C18D-97DD-4D40-84EC-AFA065B97846';
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_2_outbound]    with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_2_outbound'   , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = '48FED7D4-0116-4146-9FD1-0BF2932D87E1';
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_3_outbound]    with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_3_outbound'   , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = '07DD4094-07A6-4A56-93DB-9F9DD165D1EB';
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_4_outbound]    with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_4_outbound'   , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = 'B199DE3A-F3EE-4535-A086-5AD3A24C650D';
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_5_outbound]    with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_5_outbound'   , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = '925F764F-F0C8-4D7E-B09D-3B2EF6D61A83';
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_6_outbound]    with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_6_outbound'   , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = '887BBBE3-BC72-4D89-A5B0-43231C604596';
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_7_outbound]    with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_7_outbound'   , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = '18231D38-7695-4E1B-B017-93A4C25B5679';
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_8_outbound]    with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_8_outbound'   , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = '85CFE9EF-A33E-4173-A17C-6C7DB26B2619';
create route [route_toservicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_9_outbound]    with service_name = 'servicebrokersender_serviceBrokertest_9_outbound'   , address = 'TCP://servicebrokersender:4022', broker_instance = '6860CDAC-F0AB-4634-BA0E-4FA79C04B539';
go
```

```
-- End dialogs activation procedure on servicebrokersender:
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)
      , @name sysname
declare cur cursor  local fast_forward for
select name from sys.databases
  where name like 'serviceBrokertest_%' 
open cur
fetch next from cur into @name
while ( @@fetch_status = 0 )
begin
   select @cmd = '  use [' + @name + ']
go
create or alter procedure dbo.usp_sender_queue_outbound_activation
as
begin

    set xact_abort on;

    declare @handle             uniqueidentifier
          , @messageTypeName    sysname
          , @messageBody        varbinary(max);

    set transaction isolation level read committed;

    begin transaction;

    receive top(1) @handle = conversation_handle
                 , @messageTypeName = message_type_name
                 , @messageBody = message_body
        from [sender_queue_outbound];

    if @handle is not null
    begin

        if @messageTypeName = N''http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog''
        begin

            end conversation @handle;

        end        
        else 
        begin
            -- just in case
            raiserror(N''Service Broker: Description:"%s"'',0, 0, @messageTypeName) with log;

        end;
    end

    commit;

end
go
alter queue [sender_queue_outbound] with activation (
  status = on
, max_queue_readers = 1
, procedure_name = dbo.usp_sender_queue_outbound_activation
, execute as ''dbo'');
go
'
    print @cmd -- and exec
  fetch next from cur into @name
end
close cur
deallocate cur
go
```

```
-- Permissions on servicebrokertarget:
grant send on service::[serviceBrokertestTargetDb_inbound] to public;
go
```

So, Service Broker infrastructure is ready, let's open 3000 dialogs from every sender database:

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)
      , @name sysname
declare cur cursor  local fast_forward for
select name from sys.databases
  where name like 'serviceBrokertest_%' 
open cur
fetch next from cur into @name
while ( @@fetch_status = 0 )
begin
   select @cmd = '  use [' + @name + ']
                    declare @handle uniqueidentifier;
                    begin dialog conversation @handle 
                        from service [servicebrokersender_' + @name + '_outbound]
                        to   service ''serviceBrokertestTargetDb_inbound''
                            on contract [test_contract]
                        with encryption = off;
                    ;send on conversation @handle 
                      message type [test_message]( ''TestServiceBrokerMessage'' );
                 '
    declare @i int = 0;
    while ( @i < 3000 )
    begin
        exec ( @cmd )
        set @i += 1;
    end

  fetch next from cur into @name
end
close cur
deallocate cur
go
```

servicebrokertarget:

```
-- Check the result
select count(*) from sys.conversation_endpoints where [state] = 'CO' -- 30000 rows
select count(*) from dbo.target_queue_inbound -- 30000 rows
go
```

And close dialogs from target side. It's a imitation of real workload
servicebrokertarget:

```
while exists ( select * from sys.conversation_endpoints where [state] = 'CO' )
begin
    declare @cmd nvarchar(max) = ''
    select top 1000 @cmd += ';end conversation ' + '''' + cast( conversation_handle as nvarchar(128 ) ) +''' ' from sys.conversation_endpoints where [state] = 'CO'
    exec ( @cmd );
end
```

Before dialogs closing I've set up xEvent session with broker events on both sides.

And what I see on servicebrokersender ( session filtered by *broker_message_undeliverable* event ):
[image]

There were errors in some chunk of dialogs during `end conversation` process on the sender side. On the screenshot the amount of dialogs ended with the error is 3521 but it could be a random number. After that looks like conversations was closed eventually and I don't see any conversations ( using *sys.conversation_endpoints* ) on the sender side and all conversations on target side are in CLOSED state.

Let's consider some of the errored conversations deeply.

First one:

servicebrokersender:
[image]
servicebrokertarget:
[image]

Second one:

servicebrokersender:
[image]
servicebrokertarget:
[image]

So, I see that the situation could be related to time lag between `end conversation` on the sender side and acknowledgment on the target side. But I don't know for sure.

So, my questions:

1. Why it happens?
2. Should I care about this? I mean maybe the errors could lead to resource leak or smth like that

---

**UPDATE**

According to [David](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft) remarks:

1. I've added logging in senders activation stored procedures

```
-- End dialogs activation procedure on servicebrokersender:
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)
      , @name sysname
declare cur cursor  local fast_forward for
select name from sys.databases
  where name like 'serviceBrokertest_%' 
open cur
fetch next from cur into @name
while ( @@fetch_status = 0 )
begin
   select @cmd = '  use [' + @name + ']
go
drop table if exists dbo.activation_proc_logging
go
create table dbo.activation_proc_logging (
  get_date              datetime
, conversation_handle   uniqueidentifier
, message_type_name     sysname
, message_body          varbinary(max)
, [status]              bit
, [status_date]         datetime
)
go
create or alter procedure dbo.usp_sender_queue_outbound_activation
as
begin

    set xact_abort on;

    declare @handle             uniqueidentifier
          , @messageTypeName    sysname
          , @messageBody        varbinary(max);

    set transaction isolation level read committed;

    begin transaction;

    receive top(1) @handle = conversation_handle
                 , @messageTypeName = message_type_name
                 , @messageBody = message_body
        from [sender_queue_outbound];

    insert into dbo.activation_proc_logging ( get_date, conversation_handle, message_type_name, message_body, [status], [status_date] )
      select getdate(), @handle, @messageTypeName, @messageBody, 0, getdate()

    if @handle is not null
    begin

        if @messageTypeName = N''http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog''
        begin

            end conversation @handle;
            update dbo.activation_proc_logging
              set [status] = 1, [status_date] = getdate()
              where conversation_handle = @handle

        end        
        else 
        begin
            -- just in case
            raiserror(N''Service Broker: Description:"%s"'',0, 0, @messageTypeName) with log;

        end;
    end

    commit;

end
go
alter queue [sender_queue_outbound] with activation (
  status = on
, max_queue_readers = 1
, procedure_name = dbo.usp_sender_queue_outbound_activation
, execute as ''dbo'');
go
'
    print @cmd -- and exec
  fetch next from cur into @name
end
close cur
deallocate cur
go
```

2. I've performed conversations ending one by one

```
set nocount on;
select 'end conversation ''' + cast( conversation_handle as nvarchar(128) ) + ''';'  from sys.conversation_endpoints where [state] = 'CO'
-- 30000 rows
```

Result the same: I have this kind of errors.
I even got a new error message: "*This message could not be delivered because the 'receive end conversation' action cannot be performed in the 'DISCONNECTED_INBOUND' state.*" related to some conversations

servicebrokersender:
[image]

Unfortunatelly, xEvents session was stopped for servicebrokertarget:

What about `dbo.activation_proc_logging` tables ( `status = 1` means that conversation was ended ):

```
-- sum is 30000
select sum( cnt ) from (
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_1.dbo.activation_proc_logging  where status = 1 union all
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_2.dbo.activation_proc_logging  where status = 1 union all
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_3.dbo.activation_proc_logging  where status = 1 union all
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_4.dbo.activation_proc_logging  where status = 1 union all
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_5.dbo.activation_proc_logging  where status = 1 union all
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_6.dbo.activation_proc_logging  where status = 1 union all
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_7.dbo.activation_proc_logging  where status = 1 union all
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_8.dbo.activation_proc_logging  where status = 1 union all
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_9.dbo.activation_proc_logging  where status = 1 union all
select count(*) as cnt from serviceBrokertest_10.dbo.activation_proc_logging where status = 1 ) z
```

Every conversation was ended.

---

**UPDATE_2**

Actually the amount of rows in every senders logging table

```
select count(*) from dbo.activation_proc_logging
```

equals 3001, not 3000. Because there was another one message with `conversation_handle is null`, `message_type_name is null`, `message_body is null`. I don't know what this is

Comment: Can you tweak the repro so you are sure to send exactly 3000 END CONVERSATION's.  What you have _should_ do that, but if there is a delay between END CONVERSATION and the conversation switching to DI in sys.conversation_endpoints that could cause your current code to attempt to end the same conversation twice.  And I would also update your sender's activation procedure to record each conversation handle it ends to show that it's not ending the conversation.

Comment: I've updated the topic